# Fullpage.js onSlideLeave trigger CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

How can I trigger CSS class to start my logo animation when scrolling/changing slide with fullpage.js?

I have this (it works alright) for animating my SVG wheel logo:

```
.logo-img:hover #wheel {
    -webkit-animation: in 1s;
    transform-origin: 49% 50%;
}

#wheel {
    -webkit-animation: out 1s;
    transform-origin: 49% 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
    from   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

It's a simple animation of spinning wheel 360deg., now I want it to spin when scrolling and use "in/out" keyframes depending on sliding page up or down.

I'm using fullpage.js and jquery v2.2.4

I hope It makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the fullpage.js [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs).

So you can do:

```
.fp-viewing-section1-slide1 .myItem{
     /*Whatever */
}
```

See my video tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=5s